# can't run bartMachine parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, java

bartMachine package for R should rely in parallel processing for reducing computing time, however I can't find how to make it work: the documentation of the packages repeats that it supports parallel processing, but there are no instruction for how to make it do it, and I can see that only one of the logical cores of my pc is working.

I use ubuntu 16.04.4 and I tied installing bartMachine via compilation from source, as recommended by [its github page](https://github.com/kapelner/bartMachine), thought I'm not sure I did everything correctly.

what can I do to make bartMachine finally work in parallel?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried running `set_bart_machine_num_cores(num_cores)` in R before running `bartMachine`? This did the trick for me.

See https://rdrr.io/cran/bartMachine/man/set_bart_machine_num_cores.html